# Extending a class in nltk. - python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, nltk, wordnet

The aim is to add additional functions to the wordnet class in `nltk`, e.g.:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

class WN(wordnet):
    def foobar(self):
        print 'foobar'

x = WN
WN.foobar()
```

but it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/workspace/pybabel-fresh/babelnet/utils/pybabel_WordNet.py", line 5, in <module>
    class WN(wordnet):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 44, in __init__
    assert issubclass(reader_cls, CorpusReader)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

So I tried with `nltk.corpus.reader.WordNetCorpusReader`
(http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html#WordNetCorpusReader):

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import WordNetCorpusReader

class WN(WordNetCorpusReader):
    def __init__(self):
        self = WN.__init__()

    def foobar(self):
        return "foobar"

x = WN
x.foobar()
```

Still it seems like if I'm using WordNetCorpusReader, I need to instantiate it, so I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/workspace/pybabel-fresh/babelnet/utils/pybabel_WordNet.py", line 13, in <module>
    x.foobar()
TypeError: unbound method foobar() must be called with WN instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Then I tried:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import WordNetCorpusReader

class WN(WordNetCorpusReader):
    def foobar(self):
        return "foobar"

x = WN
for i in x.all_synsets():
    print i
```

[out]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/workspace/pybabel-fresh/babelnet/utils/pybabel_WordNet.py", line 10, in <module>
    for i in x.all_synsets():
TypeError: unbound method all_synsets() must be called with WN instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

**How do I extend the nltk wordnet API with new functions?** Note: that the aim is to create a new class with the new functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second attempt seems closest. The problem there is with your constructor:

> ```
> class WN(WordNetCorpusReader):
>     def __init__(self):
>         self = WN.__init__()  # needs an instance as the first argument, recursive, and no need to assign to self
> ```

The `__init__` method needs an instance as its first argument (here `self`), and in addition you are calling the `__init__` method of the wrong class. This will lead to a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error. Finally, you simply want to call the method; you don't need to assign the results of the method to `self`.

I think you meant to do this instead:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import WordNetCorpusReader
import nltk

class WN(WordNetCorpusReader):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        WordNetCorpusReader.__init__(self, *args)

    def foobar(self):
        return "foobar"
```

The catch is, though, that you will need to pass the required `WordNetCorpusReader.__init__` args to your new class. In my version of `nltk`, that means you will need to pass a `root` argument as follows:

```
>>> x = WN(nltk.data.find('corpora/wordnet'))
>>> x.foobar()
'foobar'
>>> x.synsets('run')
[Synset('run.n.01'), Synset('test.n.05'), ...]
```

**A more efficient approach**

A much more efficient way to do the same thing is as follows:

```
class WN(WordNetCorpusReader):
    root = nltk.data.find('corpora/wordnet')  # make root a class variable, so you only need to load it once
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        WordNetCorpusReader.__init__(self, WN.root, *args, **kwargs)  # add root yourself here, so no arguments are required

    def foobar(self):
        return "foobar"
```

Now test it:

```
>>> x = WN()
>>> x.foobar()
'foobar'
>>> x.synsets('run')
[Synset('run.n.01'), Synset('test.n.05'), ...]
```

By the way, I've enjoyed seeing your work on the `nltk` tag.

Comment: thank you for the solution!! The substantiation was driving me nuts and maybe it has to do with my 28 hours (and going) streak =)

Comment: @alvas Glad to help. Wow, 28 hours . . . . Sounds like you need a break! Cheers.